# Decrypting with a PEM RSA key using pycrypto ,

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to decrypt a message in hexadecimal format using a private key which is also in hexadecimal format with Python and the pycrypto module included. Everytime I write the last line of code,"rsakey..." I get the error "binAscii.Error:Incorrect padding". I know this works using pycrypto and not M2Crypto because a colleague already succeded in decrypting the message. What am I missing? I forgot to mention that I entered "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----" at the beginning and END at the end of the key.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = open("/path/to/key", "r").read()
rsakey = RSA.importKey(key)
```

Comment: Please show us all of the code, including how you handle IO and the file itself.

Comment: This is all the code. By default, the key file is a continous sequence of hexadecimal characters with no newline. The "file" command returns <PEM RSA private key>  when apllied to the key file (I'm on Linux). By all the code do you mean the full error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----` is for PEM encoded (also known as ASCII armored) keys. Those keys should be PKCS#8 or #12 DER encoded private keys, then encoded to base 64 and surrounded by the start and ending lines (as you described).

Just putting   `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----` around the data won't cut it.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the late response but I was having a hard time with the base64 command implemented in Linux. It turns out that encoding the key in base64 using the Linux command makes it impossible to load it into an RSA private key object in Python. The command does not include padding and will most likely alter the key, causing failure of decryption. After many tries, I tried encoding using a website, which resolved the padding issue and succesfully decrypted the message. Thank you for your response and sorry again for the late checkmark.

Comment: Also, I seemed to have a problem with my Pycrypto installation, because I was unable to import anything from Crypto.Cipher. After research on the Internet, I found out that there are some people who have this problem and there is currently no solution posted other than reinstalling the Pycrypto module until it works.